# Brother QL Series Label Printer CUPS printer server not working with P-Touch Multiple Copies

Tags: samba, network-printer, cups, brother-printer, label-printer

I have a Brother QL 500 series printer that is shared over a network using CUPS and SAMBA on an ODROID Ubuntu Server. On my desktop computer running Windows 10 and using the latest version of brother P-touch I am only able to print one label at a time which is annoying when you have 400 labels to print.

Looking online most people who experience this issue are those using HP printers over a network and need to disable Mopier Mode, the printer driver issued by Brother has no such option.

I'm not sure if this is a Windows problem, a cups problem or the software I'm using P-Touch. Hopefully, someone has had a similar problem and can point me in the right direction.

---

***CUPS Settings:***

*Image 1:*

[image: Cups image one]

*Image 2:*

[image: Cups image two]

---

***Windows 10 Driver Settings***

*Image 1:*

[image: Printer Driver Settings 1]

*Image 2:*

[image: Printer Driver Settings 2]

*Image 3:*

[image: Printer Driver Settings 3]

---

***P-Touch Settings***

*Image 1:*

[image: P-Touch Multiple Copies]

As far as I know the Brother QL-500 supports printing via a printer server as mentioned here:

> [Can multiple P-touch printers be connected to the print server?](http://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=lpql550euk&faqid=faqp00000476_000)
>
> Only one P-touch printer can be connected.
>   Connect the print server and a P-touch printer on a one to one basis using a USB cable.
>   Other devices such as a USB hub cannot be connected between the print server and a P-touch printer.
>   If you require multiple P-touch printers to be connected on your network, install one PS-9000 print server per P-touch printer.

Comment: I have no idea whether this is the problem, but happened to notice one setting. In image 1, there is a concatenate pages setting, and it's set to individual pages.  It would be a simple thing to test changing that setting to ConcatPages.

Comment: Thanks, just tried it but sadly the same problem exists.

Comment: Is the label printer connected to a PC?  If so, try printing multiple labels at that PC.

Comment: It's connected to the network using CUPS which is a common print server and very widely used in both the home and the office. It works using USB but I need to share it with other users over the network without having to share it through a PC.

Comment: Right.  But are you able to print multiple copies at the machine it is connected to?  I suspect that the print job is not producing multiple actual copies, just adding a parameter for the number of copies to print.  If that parameter is not recognized on a remote print job, it would explain the single copy.

Comment: You might be right, looking at this [PDF](https://www.ptouchdirect.com/content/UMQL550.pdf) it mentions using PS-9000 Print Server and no mention of 3rd parties. That said it does say in their FAQ to use multiple label printers on a network you need to use the PS-9000. Maybe its poorly worded and the label printer will only work fully using their own printer server which seems a little silly.

Comment: I'm a little confused with the talk about LPR ports through.

Comment: It could be that CUPS doesn't support all of the print job control options available in the Brother driver.